# Jackson Objectmapper on value of field?

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

I am using Jackson `ObjectMapper` to convert to JSON string. I want to use a `PropertyNamingStrategy` so that my fields can be given different names.

Ex: `attribute ---> attr, name --> nm`

```
OBJECT MAPPER:---> JSON STRING:
{
  "attribute" : [ {
    "name" : "accessPolicyIDs",
    "value" : "R400"
  }, {
    "name" : "maxOfInstances",
    "value" : "10"
  } ]
}
```

I can achieve this as by following class:

```
public class LongNameShortNameNamingStrategy extends PropertyNamingStrategyBase {

    @Override
    public String translate(String propertyName) {

        String shortName = null;
        shortName = LongNameShortNames.getShortName(propertyName);
        if (shortName != null){
            return shortName;
        }

        return propertyName;
    }
}
```

However, now there is a requirement to convert the value inside `name` attribute to short name too. Ex:
 `accessPolicyIDs --> acp, maxOfInstances --> mxi`

How can this be achieved ?? 
Can `ObjectMapper` be configured to work on value of a particular field??

Comment: why don't you use @JsonProperty() to change field name?

Comment: My POJO can't be edited. So used a `NamingStrategy`. And I need to change the **value** of `name` field.

Comment: Thats a weird requirement, I think this can be achieved using a custom serializer/deserializer if you are not able to modify your object classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try create custom ValueSerializer.
Something like:

```
public class CustomValueSerializer extends JsonSerializer<String> {

   @Override
   public void serialize(String s, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator,
                         SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {    

       if(jsonGenerator.getOutputContext().getCurrentName().equals("name")){
          s = getShortName(s);
       }
       jsonGenerator.writeString(s);
   }

   @Override
   public Class<String> handledType() {
       return String.class;
   }

   private String getShortName(String s){
      //make string short
   }
}
```

To use this serializer, add it to mapper:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addSerializer(new CustomValueSerializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);
String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(person);
```

Also, if you have access to pojo, you can mark `Name` property with annotation:

```
@JsonProperty
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomValueSerializer.class)
public String getName(){
  return name;
}
```